# What does "host-specific" mean in RFCs?

Tags: dhcp, terminology

What does "host-specific" mean in [RFC 1531](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/inline-errata/rfc1531.html)?

I know that "host-specific" has a meaning of "capable of living solely on or in one species of host, as a parasite that infests only chickens."

But I can't understand why "host-specific" related to `dhclient`.

> The Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) provides configuration
> parameters to Internet hosts.  DHCP consists of two components: ***a
> protocol for delivering host-specific configuration parameters*** from a
> DHCP server to a host and a mechanism for allocation of network
> addresses to hosts.

Comment: What is the question about Unix and/or Linux?

Comment: This question is about the "host-specific" term on dynamic host configuration protocol RFC that ISC uses. I want to understand ISC-DHCP service.

Comment: And bear in mind... the host could also be Windows, Mac, smartphones, sbc's etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Individual hosts on a network. You can apply different settings to each.